# Argument of NoneType is not iterable - Running Dataflow job with Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, airflow

I want to run a self executing DataFlow jar on Airflow.
I get the exception when I run the below command:

```
"airflow test test-dag hello-dag 2018-03-26"
```

What do I lost something? I cannot find more information about this.
very thanks for your help.

some versions:
python 2.7.10
airflow 1.9.0
pandas 0.22.0

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 528, in test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1584, in run
    session=session)
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 121, in execute
    hook.start_java_dataflow(self.task_id, dataflow_options, self.jar)
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 149, in start_java_dataflow
    task_id, variables, dataflow, name, ["java", "-jar"])
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 143, in _start_dataflow
    self.get_conn(), variables['project'], name).wait_for_done()
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 31, in __init__
    self._job = self._get_job()
  File "/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/py27venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 49, in _get_job
    if 'currentState' in job:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

code:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import json

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataFlowJavaOperator

default_args = {
  'owner': 'airflow',
  'depends_on_past': False,
  'start_date': datetime(2018, 3, 26),
  'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
  'email_on_failure': False,
  'email_on_retry': False,
  'retries': 2,
  'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
  'dataflow_default_options': {
    'project': 'test-123456',
    'zone': 'europe-west1-b',
    'stagingLocation': 'gs://hellodag/temp'
  }
}

my_dag = DAG('test-dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1))

task_3 = DataFlowJavaOperator(
  jar = '/Users/henry/Documents/workspace/helloairflow/target/helloairflow-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar', 
  options = {
    'autoscalingAlgorithm': 'BASIC',
    'maxNumWorkers': '50',
    'start': '{{ds}}',
    'partitionType': 'DAY',
  },
  gcp_conn_id = 'gcp_service_account',
  task_id = 'hello-dag',
  dag=my_dag)
```

Comment: I find the cause, the options need match the arguments in your Java file. if the .jar cause exception, the airflow also cause the exception.

Comment: Could you submit an answer for this with your comment, please?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ....

According to the setting of options in task_3, the Airflow will execute below command

```
java -jar helloairflow-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --autoscalingAlgorithm=BASIC --maxNumWorkers=50 --start= --partitionType=DAY ...
```

But I did not define both properties "start" and "partitionType" in my main function of helloairflow-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar then I performed above command at another terminal, I got below exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class interface com.henry.cloud.dataflow.connector.MariaDBConnector$MariaDBConnOptions missing a property named 'start'.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1579)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$400(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:291)
    at com.henry.cloud.dataflow.connector.MariaDBConnector.main(MariaDBConnector.java:90)
```

finally I removed the both properties in options of task_3, It work well.